# Getting "com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain error -2" error while doing commit to svn using xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, svn

I am getting error "com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain error -2" while I am going to commit my code in svn using xcode.

Please let me know how to resolve above error.

Answer (score 1):

May be due wrong SVN username or password.